# "what I am" or "what am I"

Tags: word-order, questions

What is the difference between/which is right:
"What I am doing wrong"
vs
"What am I doing wrong"
?

Comment: There's not enough context in your quotes. Are those sentences questions, or statements? It's the word-order which determines which is which, so it's not possible to say which one is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*What I am doing wrong* is not a direct question, it is a statement or an indirect question like:

> Feel free to correct what I am doing wrong.
>
> I want to find out what I am doing wrong.

Whereas *What am I doing wrong?* is a direct question.

In direct questions the auxiliary verb *am* should become before the subject *I*.